# Writing to a file in Java: Cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, logging, io, file-writing

I am having *enormous* difficulty writing to a simple text file in Java. Every search I've done for the IO exception I'm getting is turning up plenty of suggestions, but none of them apply to this situation.

Here is my project structure:

```
MyEclipseProject/
    src/
        com.myprogram.utils
            MyProgram
    bin/
```

And my code for **MyProgram.java**:

```
package com.myprogram.utils;

import java.io.FileWriter;

public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileWriter oWriter = new FileWriter(new File("logs/system.log"));
        oWriter.write("This never gets logged because JRE can't find the file");
    }
}
```

The exception message I'm getting states: *logs\system.log (The system cannot find the path specified)*.

The first time I tried, I did so without having first created the `logs/` directory and its subsequent log file. My understanding was that, if Java couldn't find the file, it would create it for you.

I have now placed a `logs` folder - with a blank `system.log` file - inside: (1) my project root (`MyEclipseProject`), (2) the `src/` folder, (3) the `src/com.myprogram.utils` package, and (4) the `bin` folder, and I am getting the same exact error. I'm wondering: could I have an OS/persmissions thing going on? Could my app be *trying* to create the folder and log file but be getting denied permission to do so by Windows 7? If so, what do I do?!?!

If not, where in tarnation do I place `logs/system.log`???

Thank you for any clarity to this!

Comment: Would you try changing the file name to simply system.log, and posting what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see which directory you are in, add the following print statement:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

This will tell you where you should create the `logs` directory.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response! I followed your advice and found the correct directory to place everything in. *However* I am now facing a separate issue: every time I run my program, its creating a new version of my log file; completely overwriting any data that was previously in it. And to make things more complicated, its overwriting the previous file with a blank (0 bytes) file - nothing is actually being logged. But I'm not getting any checked/unchecked exceptions either....ideas?

Comment: @Mara You need to create the `FileWriter` with the append option so that it appends to the file rather than overwriting it. You also need to `flush()` and `close()`the writer after you have written to it.

Comment: @Mara Also, please use a `BufferedWriter`. Take a look at the File IO tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html for the right way to write a file.

Answer (score 0):

try BufferedWriter

```
public static void main(String[] args {

String filename = "C:\\mynewtextfile.txt";
FileWriter fstream;
   try {
   fstream = new FileWriter(filename);
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("My Name is Bobby");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("This is my text file.");                       
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } 
   catch (IOException e) {
            e.getClass();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Path you are using is relative to current working directory. Your current working directory depends on how are you running your application. I guess it is MyEclipseProject. So, you have to create directory `log` under your project (at the same level where `src` and `bin` directories are) and then create file `system.log` into this directory. Then try again. I believe your code will start working.

It it does not try to print `new File("logs/system.log").getAbsolutePath()`  before writing to file. It will show you where the system is expecting to see your file.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a file path on modern filesystems (at least, this is true for Windows, Mac, and the flavors of Linux that I am familiar with), there are absolute paths and there are relative paths. An absolute path is the path through the filesystem down to the specific file you are looking for, such as `C:\Program Files\Application\application.exe`. Relative paths are (as implied) relative to the current location.

If I run `main()` with the line 'System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());', for example, I get the output

`C:\my-workspace\myproject\.`

The `.` represents the current directory. That's why you can use that to find where the directory should be created.

You are correct that Java will create the file if it can't find it, but the same is not true of the directory. You have to create the directory either prior to running the code or in code itself using the `File#mkdir()` method.

Answer (score 0):

depends how you call the application, but you should create logs directory inside project root and you should be able to write a file in there.

Java won't by itself create this directory during opening a stream.

You can have problem with permissions. Try:

```
System.out.println("can write: " + new File(./logs).canWrite());
```